# Programming resources to learn C in depth

Tags: c

I have been associated with C language during my college and soon shifted to scripting languages. Now I am interested to brush off my C skills and also enhance with C internals programming. I request for good resources (books, websites, articles, ...) to learn and get me started off.

Comment: http://aelinik.free.fr/c/  ; nicely done. And to not to forget use google docs with your private notes, i had same issue like yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[K&R, Second Edition](http://www.powells.com/biblio/2-9780131103627-32)

Often times the best source is the original source :)

[Expert C Programming, Deep C Secrets](http://www.powells.com/cgi-bin/biblio?inkey=4-0131774298-0)

Excellent stories of how professional programmers have been bitten by hard-to-find problems and how you can learn from their efforts.

[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](http://www.powells.com/biblio/0131411543)

THE resource for learning how to program for Unix environments; it may be lacking some of the neater new features, but it is one of the best resources for learning details of how to write systems programs.

Comment: Third book is so yum yum yum.... (reading and getting excited http://sources.sytes.net/unix/Advanced.Programming.UNIX.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

One way is, certainly, to read other people's code. That way you will see how other programmers use the language, and be forced to think through how the various constructs work.

This can be a bit hard, since many existing projects are large, and/or not very well documented. Synthesizing a project's architecture from the code alone can be hard. Try to find a reasonably-sized (e.g. *not* the Linux kernel) open source C project, that also has at least some rudimentary support/documentation for newcomers to the code.